# What adjective can designate an inventory item that is unwanted and slotted for disposal for a non-specific reason (not damaged, obsolete, extra)?

Tags: figures-of-speech

I am looking for an adjective to describe drums at a manufacturing facility and that have been deemed unwanted and planned to be scrapped, recycled or disposed in some way.  They may be empty, have obsolete product, or partially empty.

- They are not scrap drums, because they may contain material making them unfit for scrapping.
- They are not obsolete, because they may be unwanted because they are empty.
- They are not junk .. . because I don't like that term.
- They are not waste, because waste drums are considered those already filled with waste (not empty).
- They are not disregarded, because they are being dealt with and not ignored.
- They are not outcast, may be someday, but not at this point.
- They are not excommunicated .   . . again, maybe someday by some religious sect.

. . .  maybe some nautical term for stuff to staged to be thrown overboard?

. . .  maybe some personal term for a partner that is doomed to broken up with?

. . .  maybe some medical term for a limb that's to be amputated?

. ..  . I'm grasping here folks. . .

.. .. . . help!!!

Answer (score 1):

redundant, superfluous, dispensable, needless, expendable, unnecessary, spare, gratuitous, abundant, otiose, supernumerary, not needed, odd, excess, surplus

Comment: I feel like this could do with some explanation as to why any of these words would work better than the ones OP has already rejected. Right now it just feels like spitballing.

Answer (score 0):

You say "...are planned to be scrapped, recycled, **or disposed [of] in some way.**"

The correct adjective for that is "disposable".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, great food for though . .. . .need to chew on it now.

Answer (score 0):

> . . . maybe some nautical term for stuff to staged to be thrown
> overboard?
> . . . maybe some personal term for a partner that is doomed to broken
> up with?
> . . . maybe some medical term for a limb that's to be amputated?
> . .. . I'm grasping here folks. . .
>
> .. .. . . help!!!

### World Build

Industrial manufacturing and shipping have a weird (almost ironic) aesthetic of bright colors and safety euphemisms. It's someone's job to move these barrels around, and it's some manager's job to make sure they go where they're suppose to go.

It's probably someone else's job to come up with words to remind employees of the valuable 'potential' of things that look like garbage, but could easily shave several percentage points off the bottom line.

You seem to be emphasizing the 'end' of the cycle, so I suggest exploring some ironic terms for re-birth, or 'seeds', or some other (unlikely) wonderful thing that might happen someday to those barrels.

### What's the theme of your story?

Rather than just some random metaphor, pick something that reflects the theme.

If this is a dystopia, or espionage, or a comedy – or if this factory represents a soul-crushing grind, or Lovecraftian squid conspiracy – this location means something, and so this detail of the location should help reinforce the tone and narrative direction.

Answer (score 0):

Most factories have rejected or factory rejected.  It's actually quite common in manufacturing as there are obvious defects in a product that impact the brand's quality.  This is especially true in food production, where the process of making the raw ingredients into a brand may have unusual shapes result from the baking style.  These are often perfectly edible, but do not conform to the final product's unique shape or design.  Some products do get specific terms used for them (i.e.  The jellybean brand Jelly Belly calls their rejects "Flops".  The reason for this is actually for marketing purposes.  The sell huge bags of their rejects in the gift shop at the end of their factory tour under the brand of "Belly Flops" The tour stresses that the flops are no different in flavor of an acceptable jellybean of the same flavor.  Rather, the bean was rejected because it doesn't meet the specific measurements and shapes they require for acceptance (The bean is too small, too big, malformed (i.e. is not shaped like a bean) or fused with another bean at some point in the process.).

The term denotes that the final product was not packaged for shipping to a vendor because it did not meet the standards.

Answer (score -1):

Although not exact, I ended up using the phrase "Expelled Drums" because they are expelled from useful inventory.